# Do you use "in" or "into" or "on"?

Tags: grammar

Do you use "in" or "into" or "on" in this sentence?
Our site is **into** Windows Server at the moment.

Comment: It's difficult to answer your question properly because I'm not sure what your intended meaning is. Maybe your site is running a story about Windows Server, which makes *on* feasible, though it seems unlikely to me. Maybe your site is focused on everything about Windows Server, which makes *into* sound okay. But if you didn't mean any of the above, like your site is hosted on a server running Windows Server, you would want to phrase it differently.

Comment: Yes. My site is hosted on a server running Windows Server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Our site is on *a* Windows Server at the moment

When talking about digital storage media, we always say items are stored *on*. *On* the disk, *on* the USB stick, *on* the server.

Comment: Except that that is a Windows server. Windows Server is an operating system, not a piece of hardware. But without further explanation from the OP it's hard to guess what is meant exactly.