# "Tired of stuffing your phone in your bra?"

Tags: prepositions

"Tired of stuffing your phone in your bra?" Is this sentence correct, or do I need to say "into your bra"

Comment: “into” is better, but in this context we would understand “in” to mean the same thing.

Comment: @StephenS Thank you! Understanding is one thing, yes, but would you say that it's technically completely wrong? Or would it sound weird?

Comment: It sounds fine. There are contexts where the slight difference might matter, but not this one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["In" or "into"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/24472/in-or-into) Also [Come in or come into or both?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/161007/) and [Do you use “in” or “into” or “on”?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/29378/) and [Put your hands “in” or “into” your pockets?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/84098/) and [“in” or “into” to help this sentence?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/72265/), among others.